# Can I compute the posterior given only conditional probabilities (between the features and between the class and features)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Here is a simple version of my problem:

**Given:** $P(y|x_1), P(y|x_2), P(x_1|y), P(x_2|y), P(x_1|x_2), P(x_2|x_1)$

**Problem:** Find the posterior $P(y|x_1,x_2)$ without any priors. Can I compute the posterior assuming the features are not independent? Can I compute the posterior if they are independent?

---

More generally, I have a complete matrix of conditional probabilities between features $x_1,...,x_m$: [$P(x_i | x_j), \forall i,j$] as well as the conditional probabilities, $P(y|x_i) \text{ and } P(x_i|y), \forall i$. Again, I am wondering if it is possible to compute to the posterior $P(y|x_1,...,x_m)$ without the independence assumption or any priors.

---

For reference, I am trying to do the above but for $n$ classes $y_1,...,y_n$ given a subset of the features $x_1,...,x_m$ (ex. $x_1,x_9,x_{12}$).

---

UPDATE 1: If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are conditionally independent given $y$ (big assumption), then

$$P(y | x_1,x_2) = \frac{P(x_1,x_2 | y)P(y)}{P(x_2 | x_1)P(x_1)}$$
$$ = \frac{P(x_1| y)P(x_2| y)P(y)}{P(x_2 | x_1)P(x_1)}$$
$$ = \frac{P(y| x_1)P(x_2| y)}{P(x_2 | x_1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Not generally, no. Having some underlying structure is what allows you to solve for it. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network) for more info. Now, if you had other information, there are ways to still solve it.
E.g.

```
P(y|x1, x2) = P(y, x1|x2)/P(x2)
P(y|x1, x2) * P(x1, x2) = P(x1, x2|y) P(y)
```

Through the summing and normalizing over the conditionals, you can work towards solving some of this, but if there's any connection between x1 and x2, you would require P(x1, x2|y) as well, and so forth for all n variables. Note that I didn't technically prove anything here, and any proof would be difficult to attain here for proving that it is impossible, so if anyone sees errors in my logic or assumptions feel free to edit this post.

For more info on this kind of computation, look at the link above or look up Bayesian Networks, where independences are modeled with DAGs, allowing for quick computation of all distributions giving a limited subsample of conditionals.

Comment: Alright, but if the x_i's are independent, then P(y|x1,x2,...,xn) = P(y|x1)*...*P(y|xn)?

Comment: Now that is definitely false. Consider two coin flip events, which each have heads (H) with probability p. Let x1 and x2 be the event in which each individual coin is head, so these are independent. Let y be the event in which both are heads. 
`P(y|both coins are heads) = 1`
However,
`P(y|coin 1 is heads) * P(y|coin 2 is heads) = p*p = p^2`

Comment: I highly recommend reading more about bayesian networks as that is the root idea that you are going for here and is more than can be easily explained on here as it depends on what you what to do and the underlying structures or assumptions of your info. It took weeks of my AI class at Berkeley to fully explain it.

Comment: Yeah that was very wrong. I updated my post with a partial answer.

Comment: Now that looks better. The math seems to check out for that, but also note P(x2|x1) = P(x2) to simplify further